# In Postgres, how to preserve newline character in COPY TO command?

Tags: postgresql

One of the column of my table contains string with '\n'.

```
postgres=# select * from stringtest ;

 id |    inputstr

----+-----------------

  1 | Name : NOC\r   +

    | \r             +

    | Detail : Detail

(1 row)
```

But when I retrieve same table with COPY TO, new line character is getting escaped

```
postgres=# COPY (select * from stringtest) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER E'\t' ;

1       Name : NOC\r\n\r\nDetail : Detail
```

How can I make COPY TO command to replace '\n' with new line ??

Expected output :

```
postgres=# COPY (select * from stringtest) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER E'\t' ;

1       Name : NOC\r
        \r
        Detail : Detail
```

How to achieve this ??

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 text formats you can use:

1. Simple delimited text
2. CSV

I believe that with the first format (the one you used) each logical line is also a physical line, meaning that there's no way around a literal '\n'. However if you use the CSV option, you can quote the string with an embedded newline:

```
test=# copy (select * from stringtest) to stdout csv;
1,"line one
linetwo"
```

Not 100% your expected output, but if CSV is fine for you - this will do the trick.

With tab delimiter:

```
test=# copy (select * from stringtest) to stdout csv delimiter E'\t';
1   "line one
linetwo"
```

Comment: I think this is as close as you'll get. `COPY TO` is designed to be compatible with `COPY FROM`, meaning that there *must* be a way to tell the literal newlines apart from the row separators (either by quoting them or escaping them).

Answer (score 2):

You need to evaluate the escapes. Something like this will work

```
echo -e "`psql -c "COPY stringtest TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER E'\t' ;"`"
```

This is properly quoted so you wont have spaces crushed. NB: it will evaluate all escapes not just '\n'

For the **reverse** operations `COPY ... FROM stdin ...` Just escape by adding a backslash before the newline. The same can be done for the tab or whatever delimiter you choose.

If you are typing in the terminal directly or running a file \

```
postgres=# COPY stringtest FROM stdin WITH DELIMITER E'\t' ;
>>Name : NOC\r\
>>\r\
>>Detail : Detail
>>\.
postgres=#
```

Or working with data in a scripting language here is the python equivalents

```
 forward or reverse 
 .replace('\\n','\n') or .replace('\n','\\n')
 .replace('\\t','\t') or .replace('\t','\\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this way:

```
(SELECT nextval('seq'), E''||inputstr||'' FROM strongest);
```

I think it is possible using `COPY`,like this:

```
postgres=# COPY (select id, E''||storage_dex||'', * from stringtest);
```